# Banshee crash when adding folders to the library

Tags: banshee, mono

Fresh install of Ubuntu 18.04. Just trying to use Banshee now.
But I can't add any folder.

Here is the terminal output :

```
[Info  21:57:45.086] Running Banshee 2.6.2: [Ubuntu Artful Aardvark (development branch) (linux-gnu, x86_64) @ 2017-08-12 03:07:49 UTC]
Gtk-Message: 21:57:45.127: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
[Warn  21:57:45.504] Impossible de se connecter à NetworkManager ou Wicd - Une connexion réseau opérationnelle est supposée disponible

(Banshee:3737): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: 21:57:46.128: attempting to add an interface (AtkComponent) to class (__gtksharp_43_Hyena_Gui_BaseWidgetAccessible) after class_init

(Banshee:3737): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: 21:57:46.130: attempting to add an interface (AtkSelection) to class (__gtksharp_44_Hyena_Data_Gui_Accessibility_ListViewAccessible+601+5b+5bBanshee_Collection_TrackInfo+2c+20Banshee_Core+2c+20Version+3d2_6_0_0+2c+20Culture+3dneutral+2c+20PublicKeyToken+3dnull+5d+5d) after class_init

(Banshee:3737): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: 21:57:46.132: attempting to add an interface (AtkTable) to class (__gtksharp_44_Hyena_Data_Gui_Accessibility_ListViewAccessible+601+5b+5bBanshee_Collection_TrackInfo+2c+20Banshee_Core+2c+20Version+3d2_6_0_0+2c+20Culture+3dneutral+2c+20PublicKeyToken+3dnull+5d+5d) after class_init
[Warn  21:57:46.144] Initialization of accessibility support for ListView widgets failed - System.ArgumentException: Invalid signal name: model_changed (in `glib-sharp')
  at GLib.Signal.Emit (GLib.Object instance, System.String detailed_signal, System.Object[] args) [0x00024] in <5a439e0caae7469886e7119d9f6bc621>:0 
  at Hyena.Data.Gui.Accessibility.ListViewAccessible`1[T].EmitModelChanged () [0x0000c] in <2339076111b44174acb3706ba9bf4e2b>:0 
  at Hyena.ThreadAssist.ProxyToMain (Hyena.InvokeHandler handler) [0x0001e] in <d5365891755f4c7d8ef677bfa27cf30a>:0 
  at Hyena.Data.Gui.Accessibility.ListViewAccessible`1[T].OnModelChanged (System.Object o, System.EventArgs a) [0x00001] in <2339076111b44174acb3706ba9bf4e2b>:0 
  at Hyena.Data.Gui.Accessibility.ListViewAccessible`1[T]..ctor (GLib.Object widget) [0x00098] in <2339076111b44174acb3706ba9bf4e2b>:0 
  at Hyena.Data.Gui.ListViewAccessibleFactory`1[T].Init () [0x00007] in <2339076111b44174acb3706ba9bf4e2b>:0 

(Banshee:3737): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: 21:57:46.183: attempting to add an interface (AtkSelection) to class (__gtksharp_49_Hyena_Data_Gui_Accessibility_ListViewAccessible+601+5b+5bBanshee_Collection_Database_QueryFilterInfo+601+5b+5bSystem_String+2c+20mscorlib+2c+20Version+3d4_0_0_0+2c+20Culture+3dneutral+2c+20PublicKeyToken+3db77a5c561934e089+5d+5d+2c+20Banshee_Services+2c+20Version+3d2_6_0_0+2c+20Culture+3dneutral+2c+20PublicKeyToken+3dnull+5d+5d) after class_init

(Banshee:3737): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: 21:57:46.183: attempting to add an interface (AtkTable) to class (__gtksharp_49_Hyena_Data_Gui_Accessibility_ListViewAccessible+601+5b+5bBanshee_Collection_Database_QueryFilterInfo+601+5b+5bSystem_String+2c+20mscorlib+2c+20Version+3d4_0_0_0+2c+20Culture+3dneutral+2c+20PublicKeyToken+3db77a5c561934e089+5d+5d+2c+20Banshee_Services+2c+20Version+3d2_6_0_0+2c+20Culture+3dneutral+2c+20PublicKeyToken+3dnull+5d+5d) after class_init
[Warn  21:57:46.184] Initialization of accessibility support for ListView widgets failed - System.ArgumentException: Invalid signal name: model_changed (in `glib-sharp')
  at GLib.Signal.Emit (GLib.Object instance, System.String detailed_signal, System.Object[] args) [0x00024] in <5a439e0caae7469886e7119d9f6bc621>:0 
  at Hyena.Data.Gui.Accessibility.ListViewAccessible`1[T].EmitModelChanged () [0x0000c] in <2339076111b44174acb3706ba9bf4e2b>:0 
  at Hyena.ThreadAssist.ProxyToMain (Hyena.InvokeHandler handler) [0x0001e] in <d5365891755f4c7d8ef677bfa27cf30a>:0 
  at Hyena.Data.Gui.Accessibility.ListViewAccessible`1[T].OnModelChanged (System.Object o, System.EventArgs a) [0x00001] in <2339076111b44174acb3706ba9bf4e2b>:0 
  at Hyena.Data.Gui.Accessibility.ListViewAccessible`1[T]..ctor (GLib.Object widget) [0x00098] in <2339076111b44174acb3706ba9bf4e2b>:0 
  at Hyena.Data.Gui.ListViewAccessibleFactory`1[T].Init () [0x00007] in <2339076111b44174acb3706ba9bf4e2b>:0 

(Banshee:3737): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: 21:57:46.206: attempting to add an interface (AtkSelection) to class (__gtksharp_54_Hyena_Data_Gui_Accessibility_ListViewAccessible+601+5b+5bBanshee_Collection_ArtistInfo+2c+20Banshee_Core+2c+20Version+3d2_6_0_0+2c+20Culture+3dneutral+2c+20PublicKeyToken+3dnull+5d+5d) after class_init

(Banshee:3737): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: 21:57:46.206: attempting to add an interface (AtkTable) to class (__gtksharp_54_Hyena_Data_Gui_Accessibility_ListViewAccessible+601+5b+5bBanshee_Collection_ArtistInfo+2c+20Banshee_Core+2c+20Version+3d2_6_0_0+2c+20Culture+3dneutral+2c+20PublicKeyToken+3dnull+5d+5d) after class_init
[Warn  21:57:46.207] Initialization of accessibility support for ListView widgets failed - System.ArgumentException: Invalid signal name: model_changed (in `glib-sharp')
  at GLib.Signal.Emit (GLib.Object instance, System.String detailed_signal, System.Object[] args) [0x00024] in <5a439e0caae7469886e7119d9f6bc621>:0 
  at Hyena.Data.Gui.Accessibility.ListViewAccessible`1[T].EmitModelChanged () [0x0000c] in <2339076111b44174acb3706ba9bf4e2b>:0 
  at Hyena.ThreadAssist.ProxyToMain (Hyena.InvokeHandler handler) [0x0001e] in <d5365891755f4c7d8ef677bfa27cf30a>:0 
  at Hyena.Data.Gui.Accessibility.ListViewAccessible`1[T].OnModelChanged (System.Object o, System.EventArgs a) [0x00001] in <2339076111b44174acb3706ba9bf4e2b>:0 
  at Hyena.Data.Gui.Accessibility.ListViewAccessible`1[T]..ctor (GLib.Object widget) [0x00098] in <2339076111b44174acb3706ba9bf4e2b>:0 
  at Hyena.Data.Gui.ListViewAccessibleFactory`1[T].Init () [0x00007] in <2339076111b44174acb3706ba9bf4e2b>:0 

(Banshee:3737): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: 21:57:46.211: attempting to add an interface (AtkSelection) to class (__gtksharp_59_Hyena_Data_Gui_Accessibility_ListViewAccessible+601+5b+5bBanshee_Collection_YearInfo+2c+20Banshee_Core+2c+20Version+3d2_6_0_0+2c+20Culture+3dneutral+2c+20PublicKeyToken+3dnull+5d+5d) after class_init

(Banshee:3737): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: 21:57:46.216: attempting to add an interface (AtkTable) to class (__gtksharp_59_Hyena_Data_Gui_Accessibility_ListViewAccessible+601+5b+5bBanshee_Collection_YearInfo+2c+20Banshee_Core+2c+20Version+3d2_6_0_0+2c+20Culture+3dneutral+2c+20PublicKeyToken+3dnull+5d+5d) after class_init
[Warn  21:57:46.217] Initialization of accessibility support for ListView widgets failed - System.ArgumentException: Invalid signal name: model_changed (in `glib-sharp')
  at GLib.Signal.Emit (GLib.Object instance, System.String detailed_signal, System.Object[] args) [0x00024] in <5a439e0caae7469886e7119d9f6bc621>:0 
  at Hyena.Data.Gui.Accessibility.ListViewAccessible`1[T].EmitModelChanged () [0x0000c] in <2339076111b44174acb3706ba9bf4e2b>:0 
  at Hyena.ThreadAssist.ProxyToMain (Hyena.InvokeHandler handler) [0x0001e] in <d5365891755f4c7d8ef677bfa27cf30a>:0 
  at Hyena.Data.Gui.Accessibility.ListViewAccessible`1[T].OnModelChanged (System.Object o, System.EventArgs a) [0x00001] in <2339076111b44174acb3706ba9bf4e2b>:0 
  at Hyena.Data.Gui.Accessibility.ListViewAccessible`1[T]..ctor (GLib.Object widget) [0x00098] in <2339076111b44174acb3706ba9bf4e2b>:0 
  at Hyena.Data.Gui.ListViewAccessibleFactory`1[T].Init () [0x00007] in <2339076111b44174acb3706ba9bf4e2b>:0 

(Banshee:3737): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: 21:57:46.225: attempting to add an interface (AtkSelection) to class (__gtksharp_64_Hyena_Data_Gui_Accessibility_ListViewAccessible+601+5b+5bBanshee_Collection_AlbumInfo+2c+20Banshee_Core+2c+20Version+3d2_6_0_0+2c+20Culture+3dneutral+2c+20PublicKeyToken+3dnull+5d+5d) after class_init

(Banshee:3737): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: 21:57:46.225: attempting to add an interface (AtkTable) to class (__gtksharp_64_Hyena_Data_Gui_Accessibility_ListViewAccessible+601+5b+5bBanshee_Collection_AlbumInfo+2c+20Banshee_Core+2c+20Version+3d2_6_0_0+2c+20Culture+3dneutral+2c+20PublicKeyToken+3dnull+5d+5d) after class_init
[Warn  21:57:46.226] Initialization of accessibility support for ListView widgets failed - System.ArgumentException: Invalid signal name: model_changed (in `glib-sharp')
  at GLib.Signal.Emit (GLib.Object instance, System.String detailed_signal, System.Object[] args) [0x00024] in <5a439e0caae7469886e7119d9f6bc621>:0 
  at Hyena.Data.Gui.Accessibility.ListViewAccessible`1[T].EmitModelChanged () [0x0000c] in <2339076111b44174acb3706ba9bf4e2b>:0 
  at Hyena.ThreadAssist.ProxyToMain (Hyena.InvokeHandler handler) [0x0001e] in <d5365891755f4c7d8ef677bfa27cf30a>:0 
  at Hyena.Data.Gui.Accessibility.ListViewAccessible`1[T].OnModelChanged (System.Object o, System.EventArgs a) [0x00001] in <2339076111b44174acb3706ba9bf4e2b>:0 
  at Hyena.Data.Gui.Accessibility.ListViewAccessible`1[T]..ctor (GLib.Object widget) [0x00098] in <2339076111b44174acb3706ba9bf4e2b>:0 
  at Hyena.Data.Gui.ListViewAccessibleFactory`1[T].Init () [0x00007] in <2339076111b44174acb3706ba9bf4e2b>:0 
[Info  21:57:46.404] Updating web proxy from GConf
[Info  21:57:46.447] All services are started 1,098035
[Info  21:57:46.938] nereid Client Started
[Info  21:57:46.998] GStreamer version 1.12.2.0, gapless: True, replaygain: False
free(): invalid pointer
Stacktrace:

  at <unknown> <0xffffffff>
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) GLib.SList.g_free (intptr) <0x0005f>
  at GLib.ListBase.Empty () <0x0013c>
  at GLib.ListBase.Dispose (bool) <0x0000f>
  at GLib.ListBase.Dispose () <0x00018>
  at GLib.Marshaller.ListPtrToArray<T_REF> (intptr,System.Type,bool,bool) <0x00131>
  at Gtk.FileChooserDialog.get_Uris () <0x0003b>
  at Banshee.Gui.Dialogs.GtkFileChooserDialog.Banshee.Gui.Dialogs.IBansheeFileChooser.get_Uris () <0x0000f>
  at Banshee.Library.Gui.FolderImportSource.Import () <0x0006e>
  at Banshee.Gui.GlobalActions.OnImport (object,System.EventArgs) <0x00094>
  at (wrapper runtime-invoke) <Module>.runtime_invoke_void__this___object_object (object,intptr,intptr,intptr) <0x000eb>
  at <unknown> <0xffffffff>
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoMethod.InternalInvoke (System.Reflection.MonoMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&) <0x00073>
  at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (object,System.Reflection.BindingFlags,System.Reflection.Binder,object[],System.Globalization.CultureInfo) <0x000a1>
  at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke (object,object[]) <0x0002a>
  at System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeImpl (object[]) <0x0024c>
  at System.MulticastDelegate.DynamicInvokeImpl (object[]) <0x00035>
  at System.Delegate.DynamicInvoke (object[]) <0x00019>
  at GLib.Signal.ClosureInvokedCB (object,GLib.ClosureInvokedArgs) <0x00193>
  at GLib.SignalClosure.Invoke (GLib.ClosureInvokedArgs) <0x0002f>
  at GLib.SignalClosure.MarshalCallback (intptr,intptr,uint,intptr,intptr,intptr) <0x002b3>
  at (wrapper native-to-managed) GLib.SignalClosure.MarshalCallback (intptr,intptr,uint,intptr,intptr,intptr) <0x000cf>
  at <unknown> <0xffffffff>
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) Gtk.Application.gtk_main () <0x00059>
  at Gtk.Application.Run () <0x0000b>
  at Banshee.Gui.GtkBaseClient.Run () <0x000bf>
  at Banshee.Gui.GtkBaseClient.Startup () <0x00053>
  at Hyena.Gui.CleanRoomStartup.Startup (Hyena.Gui.CleanRoomStartup/StartupInvocationHandler) <0x000ae>
  at Banshee.Gui.GtkBaseClient.Startup<T_REF> () <0x000d7>
  at Banshee.Gui.GtkBaseClient.Startup<T_REF> (string[]) <0x00137>
  at Nereid.Client.Main (string[]) <0x0001b>
  at (wrapper runtime-invoke) <Module>.runtime_invoke_void_object (object,intptr,intptr,intptr) <0x000d1>
  at <unknown> <0xffffffff>
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly (System.AppDomain,System.Reflection.Assembly,string[]) <0x0006d>
  at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssemblyInternal (System.Reflection.Assembly,string[]) <0x00044>
  at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly (string,System.Security.Policy.Evidence,string[]) <0x00034>
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly (string,System.Security.Policy.Evidence,string[]) <0x000a1>
  at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly (string) <0x0001c>
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly (string) <0x0007d>
  at Booter.Booter.BootClient (string) <0x00094>
  at Booter.Booter.Main () <0x0020b>
  at (wrapper runtime-invoke) object.runtime_invoke_void (object,intptr,intptr,intptr) <0x000c7>

Native stacktrace:

    banshee(+0xc8514) [0x5638cac90514]
    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x12890) [0x7fd3e4d49890]
    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(gsignal+0xc7) [0x7fd3e476ce97]
    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(abort+0x141) [0x7fd3e476e801]
    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x89897) [0x7fd3e47b7897]
    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x9090a) [0x7fd3e47be90a]
    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(cfree+0x4cc) [0x7fd3e47c5e1c]
    [0x408db150]

Debug info from gdb:

[New LWP 3739]
[New LWP 3740]
[New LWP 3741]
[New LWP 3742]
[New LWP 3743]
[New LWP 3747]
[New LWP 3760]
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
0x00007fd3e4d4923a in __waitpid (pid=3764, stat_loc=0x7ffc5d17cf6c, options=0) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/waitpid.c:30
30  ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/waitpid.c: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type.
  Id   Target Id         Frame 
* 1    Thread 0x7fd3e5905780 (LWP 3737) "Main Thread" 0x00007fd3e4d4923a in __waitpid (pid=3764, stat_loc=0x7ffc5d17cf6c, options=0) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/waitpid.c:30
  2    Thread 0x7fd3e37ff700 (LWP 3739) "SGen worker" 0x00007fd3e4d449f3 in futex_wait_cancelable (private=<optimized out>, expected=0, futex_word=0x5638cb183a08) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/futex-internal.h:88
  3    Thread 0x7fd3e1434700 (LWP 3740) "Finalizer" 0x00007fd3e4d476d6 in futex_abstimed_wait_cancelable (private=0, abstime=0x0, expected=0, futex_word=0x5638cb174640) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/futex-internal.h:205
  4    Thread 0x7fd3d38c0700 (LWP 3741) "HyenaSqliteConn" 0x00007fd3e4d449f3 in futex_wait_cancelable (private=<optimized out>, expected=0, futex_word=0x5638cb80ec50) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/futex-internal.h:88
  5    Thread 0x7fd3d115c700 (LWP 3742) "gmain" 0x00007fd3e4842bf9 in __GI___poll (fds=0x5638cc18cd60, nfds=2, timeout=5481) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/poll.c:29
  6    Thread 0x7fd3d095b700 (LWP 3743) "gdbus" 0x00007fd3e4842bf9 in __GI___poll (fds=0x5638cc1aaad0, nfds=3, timeout=-1) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/poll.c:29
  7    Thread 0x7fd3bfede700 (LWP 3747) "threaded-ml" 0x00007fd3e4842bf9 in __GI___poll (fds=0x7fd3b80031a0, nfds=3, timeout=1500) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/poll.c:29
  8    Thread 0x7fd39d7fa700 (LWP 3760) "pool" syscall () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/syscall.S:38

Thread 8 (Thread 0x7fd39d7fa700 (LWP 3760)):
#0  syscall () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/syscall.S:38
#1  0x00007fd3e0a93f2a in g_cond_wait_until () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#2  0x00007fd3e0a214f1 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#3  0x00007fd3e0a767a4 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#4  0x00007fd3e0a75e05 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#5  0x00007fd3e4d3e6db in start_thread (arg=0x7fd39d7fa700) at pthread_create.c:463
#6  0x00007fd3e484f88f in clone () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/clone.S:95

Thread 7 (Thread 0x7fd3bfede700 (LWP 3747)):
#0  0x00007fd3e4842bf9 in __GI___poll (fds=0x7fd3b80031a0, nfds=3, timeout=1500) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/poll.c:29
#1  0x00007fd3be2e2451 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpulse.so.0
#2  0x00007fd3be2d3e10 in pa_mainloop_poll () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpulse.so.0
#3  0x00007fd3be2d44a0 in pa_mainloop_iterate () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpulse.so.0
#4  0x00007fd3be2d4530 in pa_mainloop_run () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpulse.so.0
#5  0x00007fd3be2e2399 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpulse.so.0
#6  0x00007fd3be0842a8 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pulseaudio/libpulsecommon-11.1.so
#7  0x00007fd3e4d3e6db in start_thread (arg=0x7fd3bfede700) at pthread_create.c:463
#8  0x00007fd3e484f88f in clone () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/clone.S:95

Thread 6 (Thread 0x7fd3d095b700 (LWP 3743)):
#0  0x00007fd3e4842bf9 in __GI___poll (fds=0x5638cc1aaad0, nfds=3, timeout=-1) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/poll.c:29
#1  0x00007fd3e0a4e439 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#2  0x00007fd3e0a4e7d2 in g_main_loop_run () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#3  0x00007fd3dbd30e76 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so.0
#4  0x00007fd3e0a75e05 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#5  0x00007fd3e4d3e6db in start_thread (arg=0x7fd3d095b700) at pthread_create.c:463
#6  0x00007fd3e484f88f in clone () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/clone.S:95

Thread 5 (Thread 0x7fd3d115c700 (LWP 3742)):
#0  0x00007fd3e4842bf9 in __GI___poll (fds=0x5638cc18cd60, nfds=2, timeout=5481) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/poll.c:29
#1  0x00007fd3e0a4e439 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#2  0x00007fd3e0a4e54c in g_main_context_iteration () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#3  0x00007fd3e0a4e591 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#4  0x00007fd3e0a75e05 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#5  0x00007fd3e4d3e6db in start_thread (arg=0x7fd3d115c700) at pthread_create.c:463
#6  0x00007fd3e484f88f in clone () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/clone.S:95

Thread 4 (Thread 0x7fd3d38c0700 (LWP 3741)):
#0  0x00007fd3e4d449f3 in futex_wait_cancelable (private=<optimized out>, expected=0, futex_word=0x5638cb80ec50) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/futex-internal.h:88
#1  __pthread_cond_wait_common (abstime=0x0, mutex=0x5638cb80ec00, cond=0x5638cb80ec28) at pthread_cond_wait.c:502
#2  __pthread_cond_wait (cond=0x5638cb80ec28, mutex=0x5638cb80ec00) at pthread_cond_wait.c:655
#3  0x00005638cae1f15c in ?? ()
#4  0x00005638cae357e2 in ?? ()
#5  0x00005638cad8a74b in ?? ()
#6  0x00005638cad8c0b7 in ?? ()
#7  0x0000000040786b9f in ?? ()
#8  0x00007fd3e39b86c8 in ?? ()
#9  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()

Thread 3 (Thread 0x7fd3e1434700 (LWP 3740)):
#0  0x00007fd3e4d476d6 in futex_abstimed_wait_cancelable (private=0, abstime=0x0, expected=0, futex_word=0x5638cb174640) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/futex-internal.h:205
#1  do_futex_wait (sem=sem@entry=0x5638cb174640, abstime=0x0) at sem_waitcommon.c:111
#2  0x00007fd3e4d477c8 in __new_sem_wait_slow (sem=0x5638cb174640, abstime=0x0) at sem_waitcommon.c:181
#3  0x00005638cadacdc9 in ?? ()
#4  0x00005638cad8abe1 in ?? ()
#5  0x00005638cae4a14a in ?? ()
#6  0x00007fd3e4d3e6db in start_thread (arg=0x7fd3e1434700) at pthread_create.c:463
#7  0x00007fd3e484f88f in clone () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/clone.S:95

Thread 2 (Thread 0x7fd3e37ff700 (LWP 3739)):
#0  0x00007fd3e4d449f3 in futex_wait_cancelable (private=<optimized out>, expected=0, futex_word=0x5638cb183a08) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/futex-internal.h:88
#1  __pthread_cond_wait_common (abstime=0x0, mutex=0x5638cb183a20, cond=0x5638cb1839e0) at pthread_cond_wait.c:502
#2  __pthread_cond_wait (cond=0x5638cb1839e0, mutex=0x5638cb183a20) at pthread_cond_wait.c:655
#3  0x00005638cae18863 in ?? ()
#4  0x00007fd3e4d3e6db in start_thread (arg=0x7fd3e37ff700) at pthread_create.c:463
#5  0x00007fd3e484f88f in clone () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/clone.S:95

Thread 1 (Thread 0x7fd3e5905780 (LWP 3737)):
#0  0x00007fd3e4d4923a in __waitpid (pid=3764, stat_loc=0x7ffc5d17cf6c, options=0) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/waitpid.c:30
#1  0x00005638cac905f0 in ?? ()
#2  <signal handler called>
#3  __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:51
#4  0x00007fd3e476e801 in __GI_abort () at abort.c:79
#5  0x00007fd3e47b7897 in __libc_message (action=action@entry=do_abort, fmt=fmt@entry=0x7fd3e48e4b9a "%s\n") at ../sysdeps/posix/libc_fatal.c:181
#6  0x00007fd3e47be90a in malloc_printerr (str=str@entry=0x7fd3e48e2d88 "free(): invalid pointer") at malloc.c:5350
#7  0x00007fd3e47c5e1c in _int_free (have_lock=0, p=0x5638cc683c50, av=0x7fd3e4b19c40 <main_arena>) at malloc.c:4157
#8  __GI___libc_free (mem=0x5638cc683c60) at malloc.c:3124
#9  0x00000000408db150 in ?? ()
#10 0x00005638cc683c60 in ?? ()
#11 0x00005638cc683c60 in ?? ()
#12 0x00007fd3d00decf0 in ?? ()
#13 0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()

=================================================================
Got a SIGABRT while executing native code. This usually indicates
a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries 
used by your application.
=================================================================

Abandon (core dumped)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a simple solution that doesn't require a tome of terminal output.

Revert to an earlier version of Ubuntu. If you prefer LTS, then use 16.04, where nearly everything works and most of the bugs have been solved.

The latest is not necessarily the best. Personally, I avoid upgrading Ubuntu until after the first point release, at least.

Remember that Ubuntu LTS is still based on the Debian Testing branch, so it is still quite unstable.

It's also worth mentioning that Banshee has not received a proper update/upgrade since 2014 (Trusty), so there may be an incompatibility issue.